# How to make wx.TextEntryDialog larger and resizable

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I create a [`wx.TextEntryDialog`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TextEntryDialog-class.html) as follows:

```
import wx

dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(self, 'Rules:', 'Edit rules', 
                         style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.OK|wx.CANCEL)
dlg.SetValue(self.rules_text.Value)
if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
    …
```

This results in a dialog box that is too small for my needs, and that is not resizable:

[image: small dialog box]

My question is: **How can I make the dialog box larger and resizable?**  I tried adding the flags `wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE` and `wx.RESIZE_BORDER`, but that had no effect except to replace the text with dots:

```
dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(self, 'Rules:', 'Edit rules', 
                         style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.OK|wx.CANCEL|wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE|wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
```

[image: small, garbled dialog box]

Comment: Hmm... with `wx` 3 on Windows the resulting dialog from `wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.OK|wx.CANCEL` is resizable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Time to learn how to write your own dialogs! ;-)

The built-in dialogs such as `TextEntryDialog` are only for the most basic programs.  If you need much customization, you need to write your own dialogs.

Here's an example, this should work for you.

```
import wx

class TextEntryDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, caption):
        style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE | wx.RESIZE_BORDER
        super(TextEntryDialog, self).__init__(parent, -1, title, style=style)
        text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, caption)
        input = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        input.SetInitialSize((400, 300))
        buttons = self.CreateButtonSizer(wx.OK|wx.CANCEL)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(text, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(input, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(buttons, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.input = input
    def SetValue(self, value):
        self.input.SetValue(value)
    def GetValue(self):
        return self.input.GetValue()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    dialog = TextEntryDialog(None, 'Title', 'Caption')
    dialog.Center()
    dialog.SetValue('Value')
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        print dialog.GetValue()
    dialog.Destroy()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: The `wx.RESIZE_BORDER` flag was what I was looking for.